# Configuring a router to auto login in network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

Recently I brought a router "TP-Link 300 Mbps Wireless N Router (TL-WR841N)" and configuring it to use it with my ISP. My isp gave me a static ip configuration. So I put them in the router and it's doing good.

But the problem is I need to first enter a username & password to the browser before surfing the net. Is there any way to save this in the router so that the router can itself login with the provided credentials? I checked all the options in router panel but none worked. Is this feature available in any third party firmware? Any help will be appreciated.

Addition:

It's version 9.3. I know it's not an ADSL but not sure if its pppoe. The port is rj45 port and it directly get into my computer's LAN port and a rj45 jack is connected to its WAN port from ISP network. Then i need to put ISP specified IP in the adapter and then open a ip in my browser where i need to login with my username and pass. Then im able to browse the net. That's how i get connected.

Comment: Which version is the router (see as explained [here](http://www.tp-link.com/lk/Article/?id=46)? Is this an ADSL/PPPoE connection?

Comment: Hi. It's version 9.3. I know it's not an ADSL but not sure if its pppoe. The port is rj45 port and it directly get into my computer's LAN port. Then i need to put ISP specified IP in the adapter and then open a ip in my browser where i need to login with my username and pass. Then im able to browse the net. That's how i get connected.
Thank you.

Comment: How the router connect to internet physically (is it rj45 to a modem)?

Comment: Yes. A rj45 jack is connected to its WAN port.

Comment: anyone? Anything??

Comment: :) sorry man I forgot about you. I couldn't find any way using the router, as it seems you ISP provide a login page like in public hot spot. The only thing I can think of  is writing an auto login script from your desktop (1 click to login) . If that is not what are looking for, I'm out of ideas.